# Syntax highlighting for Hugo in WebStorm

Tags: ide, webstorm, syntax-highlighting, hugo

I have been looking around the internet for a WebStorm plugin that will help with syntax-highlighting when working with Hugo. I have not been able to find one. **Does anyone know of a Hugo WebStorm plugin that exists?** Thanks for your help.

Comment: do you mean https://github.com/spf13/hugo? What syntax do you have problems with? TOML? Markdown? Or?

Comment: Yes, spf13's Hugo. It would be specifically the Go Templating syntax that Hugo uses. It's an absolute mess as far as syntax highlighting and formatting goes.

Comment: Go is supported through [Go plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5047-go-language-golang-org-support-plugin), but it doesn't yet support templates (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-2953)

Comment: So I guess I'm out of luck until that happens. I'll keep an eye on it, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is [Go Template](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10581-go-template) plugin from JetBrains. It allows to highlight and autocomplete the basic syntax at least. The plugin works with *.gohtml files, file extensions can be customised in "Editor/File Types" preferences.